# Script to show free memory (Ram) column on `free` command in linux?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, execute-command

I want to write a script that shows available memory in my system every second with the updated value.
I have some clues like I can use the free command with the -m option to show in megabytes.
I have been through some tutorials showing cut -f2 can show the 2nd column but not working with my  BASH_VERSION: 5.0..

*my current script*

```
#! /bin/bash
CMD= 'free -m'
for((sec = 0; sec < 360; sec++))
do 
   echo $($CMD | cut -f3 )
   sleep 1
done
```

it's not working, kindly suggest.

Comment: I'd start by running your script through a syntax checker: [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: If that worked out, can you suggest some solution?